# Java Regex to match comma delimited list of interfaces

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a Java regex to match a comma delimited list of interfaces. Something like:

```
Runnable, Serializable, List, Map
```

There can be zero or more entries in the list. A trailing comma is invalid. Space is optional. I came up with the following, which gets me to one or more entries, and then check for empty:

```
String validName = "[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*";
String regex = validName + "\\s*(,\\s*" + validName + ")*";
if (s.matches(regex) || s.trim().isEmpty())
  ...
```

But is there a way to include the "zero entries" condition into the regex?

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "empty case"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a pattern optional, use a group with a `?` quantifier set to it:

```
String regex = "(?:" + validName + "\\s*(?:,\\s*" + validName + ")*)?";
//              ^^^                                                ^^
if (s.matches(regex) { 
 // ....
}
```

The `?` greedy quantifier matches one or zero occurrences of the pattern it is applied to. (greedy means it prefers to get 1 occurrence rather than 0)
The `(?:` character sequence opens a non-capturing group.  I.E. this is how you use "normal parentheses" for logically grouping sections of regular expressions.

You may add `\\s*` subpatterns at the start/end of the pattern to allow leading/trailing whitespace.

Comment: Just FYI: I suggest using  [regex101.com](http://regex101.com)  to check your patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Try  `String regex = "^$|" + regex`  ^$ means "nothing between the beginning of the input and the end of the input".  ^$| means "either match nothing or match whatever matches the rest of the regex"

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew true and it is nice to have this tool, but human written answers are usually more readable than machine generated ones (which are detailed, but level of detail is limited - they also not always can explain *idea* which regex author was trying to *implement*).

Comment: @geneSummons you could include some spaces between `^` and `$` to let regex match also only-whitespace input which OP seems to be handling with `s.trim()`. So it looks like `"^\\s*$|..."` could be better here.

Comment: Using alternatives is a valid but less efficient approach.